# What does this mean? Web Access Module can only work with TeamFoundationApplication

Tags: team-foundation-server

So I installed TFS2012 the other day and now when I try to view the web access app I get the error as shown below. Ideas?

[image: TFS 2012 server error]

Comment: From the stack, it looks like a compatibility problem between your machine and TFS. What version of IIS are you running? Did you get any warnings during the install? (You can search the install logs for "[warning]" if you can't remember)

Comment: I actually used the web access portal for an hour or so. So I'm sure it's not a corrupt installation.

Comment: Have you tried repairing TFS via Add/Remove programs > TFS > Change? It may have worked immediately after installation, but it looks like it has been corrupted in the intervening time...

Comment: TFS2012 doesn't have repair option

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. The installer does not have a repair option, but you can repair via Add/Remove Programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global.asax file in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier\Web Services folder with the following content:

```
<%@ Application Inherits="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationApplication" %>
```

Seems like something went wrong after I used the web access tool and the global.asax file went missing from the web services folder. [Discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/38588e64-ec8c-4cf3-84e3-2b6f1ac426c3) from the TFS forums.